# Import could not be resolve after installing the dependency

Tags: python, django, python-3.7, messagebird

I'm trying to install de `messagebird` dependency into my python project.

I write into `requirements.txt` and after I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` as you can see below:
[image]

But the `pylance` was still showing me the error:
[image]

Then I try to install using `pip install messagebird` but still with no success.

I also try to reopen the window but no success too.

I'm using `pyenv`, and using the right env on the vscode and terminal as you can see on the next images:

[image]

And in the terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be installing to the wrong Python distro? (could be installing to Python 2.7)

To target `python3` you can use the following commands

```sh
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Or

```sh
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

---

To check that you've installed `messagebird` correctly you could also use the following command:

```sh
pip3 freeze | grep 'messagebird'
```

Comment: It's not, but I'm using pyenv, but I have almot sure that I'm installing on the right env, I will edit my question.

Comment: I tried with pip3 and python3 but didn't work